# foreach element store in single array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

My foreach element provide three variable for each time.

How can i store it as multidimensional array.

My code to store the array is

```
foreach($parts as $part){
     $filename = $filename;
     $attachmentid = $attachmentid;
     $filelocation = $filelocation;
     $attachment = [
       'filename' => $filename,
       'attachmnetId' => $attachmentid,
       'filelocation' => $filelocation
     ];
}
```

my `print_r($attachment)` shows only last foreach array

Comment: The first 3 lines after foreach seem pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `[]` to make an array for `attachment`

```
$attachment[] = [
   'filename' => $filename,
   'attachmnetId' => $attachmentid,
   'filelocation' => $filelocation
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You had $attachment as just a string not an array

```
foreach($parts as $part){
 $filename = $filename;
 $attachmentid = $attachmentid;
 $filelocation = $filelocation;
 $attachment[] = [
   'filename' => $filename,
   'attachmnetId' => $attachmentid,
   'filelocation' => $filelocation
 ];
}
```